# Comparison of XML messages in Camel Junit

Tags: unit-testing, apache-camel

Is there a way to compare XML messages in Camel Junit?.

I am using the following code:

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:camel-context-test.xml" })
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@MockEndpoints("*")
public class CamelRoutesTest/* extends XMLTestCase */{
    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(CamelRoutesTest.class);
    @Autowired
    protected CamelContext camelContext;

    @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:d2")
    protected MockEndpoint direct1;

    @Produce(uri = "direct:d1")
    protected ProducerTemplate d1;

    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        LOG.info("Starting testTradeSaveToPL test");

            //node1 comes BEFORE node2
    String sendMsg = "<test><node1>1</node1><node2>2</node2></test>"; 

            //node1 comes AFTER node2
    String valMsg1 = "<test><node2>2</node2><node1>1</node1></test>";


        direct1.expectedBodiesReceivedInAnyOrder(valMsg1);

        d1.sendBody(sendMsg);
        direct1.assertIsSatisfied(camelContext);
    }
}
```

My problem is, in the XML message I send to the route, node1 comes before node2 while in the reply node2 comes before node1.

By looking I know both the XML are equal but since the code does String comparison, it fails.

I am aware XMLJUnit compare tools, but how can I integrate it into the given test case?

Answer (score 3):

I have integrated XMLUnit in my Camel unit tests to compare XML messages.

In your constructor, set up XMLUnit:

```
@Override
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();

    //Tell XML Unit to ignore whitespace between elements and within elements
    XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(true);
    XMLUnit.setNormalizeWhitespace(true);
}
```

Then later on you can run an assertion:

```
    Diff myDiff = new Diff(actualResponse, expectedResponseAsString);
    assertTrue("XML identical " + myDiff.toString(),
                   myDiff.identical());
```

You can use this dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xmlunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlunit</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Here is a link to the users guide:

http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/userguide/html/index.html

Since the sequence of elements is actually different, this test framework might not help you.  However, you could also just XPath API's in Java or JDOM to run your assertions as well.

Thanks,
Yogesh